# How can I link static libraries defined in CMake subprojects to targets in other subprojects?

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, static-libraries

I have a large, modular CMake project.
Some modules are static libraries, some are executables that may or may not use some of these libraries. I already have a system of requirement/dependency checking in place that would stop cmake and tell the user if he's trying to build an executable but not the library that it requires.

The project compiles fine as is. I would like to split this into subprojects, i.e. set  `project(${module_name})` for each of the modules' CMakeLists.txt. Unfortunately, as soon as I insert this line into the apppropriate macro, I immediately get linker errors, i.e. the executables can no longer see the symbols defined in the static libraries.

The c++ command (I happen to be using gcc 4.8) that is invoked on the executables is unchanged, so something else must be different. How can I fix this and retain the subproject structure?

EDIT: per @Gerald's comment, additional information.

Project folder structure:

```
root
 |
 |-bin
 |-lib
 |-cmake(various CMake scripts, added to module path)
 |-third_party
 |-...
 |-CMakeLists.txt
 |-modules(top-level module directory, expanded)
      |
      |-CMakeLists.txt
      |-exec_module_a
      |-exec_module_b
      |-... (other exec modules)
      |-lib_module_a
      |-lib_module_b
      |- ... (other lib modules)
      |-lib_module_N (expanded)
             |
             |-CMakeLists.txt
             |-include/root/module_N (various include files)
             |-src (various source files)
             |-tests
```

Structure of a typical leaf-level CMakeLists.txt (same but one arg. to root_add_subproject for both lib and exec modules):

```
include(RootUtils)

set(module_name ${EXEC_MODULE_A})
#---------------------------CHECK REQUIREMENTS---------------------------------#
root_check_module_requirements(module_name
    BUILD_${LIB_MODULE_A}
    BUILD_${LIB_MODULE_G}
    #...
    WITH_QT
    WITH_THIRD_PARTY_BLAH1
    WITH_THIRD_PARTY_BLAH2
    #...
)
#---------------------------ADD SOURCES AND TARGET-----------------------------#
root_add_subproject(${module_name} executable qt_on)
#---------------------------ADD INCLUDES---------------------------------------#
target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC

    #third-party includes
    ${THIRD_PARTY_BLAH1_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
    ${THIRD_PARTY_BLAH1_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    #...

    #module includes
    "${MODULES_DIR}/${LIB_MODULE_A}/include"
    "${MODULES_DIR}/${LIB_MODULE_B}/include"
    #...
)
#---------------------------LINK LIBRARIES-------------------------------------#
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC

    #third-party libraries
    ${QT5_TARGETS}
    ${THIRD_PARTY_BLAH1_LIBRARIES}
    ${THIRD_PARTY_BLAH2_LIBRARIES}
    #...

    #module libraries
    ${LIB_MODULE_A}
    ${LIB_MODULE_B}
    #...
)
if(UNIX)
    #... link third-party dependencies conditional on platform
endif()
#---------------------------ADD TESTS------------------------------------------#
#SET(BUILD_TESTS FALSE)#comment out to build the local unit tests
root_add_tests(${module_name})

#==============================================================================#
```

The relevant script in RootUtils.cmake looks like this:

```
macro(augmentarium_add_subproject module_name proj_type qt_on)

    if(${qt_on} STREQUAL "qt_on" OR ${qt_on} STREQUAL "YES" OR ${qt_on} STREQUAL "TRUE")
        set(QT_ON TRUE)
    else()
        set(QT_ON FALSE)
    endif()

    #---------------------------DEFINE SUBPROJECT----------------------------------#
    #TODO: fix problems with macro (figure out how to set up library as a subproject w/o destroying linking capability)
    #project(${module_name}) # <------- THIS is the line that causes linker errors

    set(TARGET_NAME ${module_name})
    string(TOUPPER "${TARGET_NAME}" TARGET_NAME_UPPER)

    if(QT_ON)
        set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
    endif()


    #---------------------------DEFINE SOURCE FILES--------------------------------#
    include_directories(include)
    SET(${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_TOP_INCLUDE_DIR include/${PROJECT_NAME}/${TARGET_NAME})

    file(GLOB ${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_CMAKELISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt)

    file(GLOB ${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_SOURCES src/*.cpp)
    file(GLOB ${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_HEADERS src/*.h src/*.h.in src/*.hpp src/*.tpp
        ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_TOP_INCLUDE_DIR}/*.h 
        ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_TOP_INCLUDE_DIR}/*.h.in 
        ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_TOP_INCLUDE_DIR}/*.hpp 
        ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_TOP_INCLUDE_DIR}/*.tpp)
    file(GLOB ${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_TEST_SOURCES  tests/*.cpp)

    if(QT_ON)
        file(GLOB_RECURSE MOC_${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_SOURCES moc_*.cpp *_automoc.cpp qrc_*.cpp)
        #remove generated moc files
        foreach(FILE_NAME ${MOC_${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_SOURCES})
            list(REMOVE_ITEM ${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_SOURCES ${FILE_NAME})
        endforeach()
    endif(QT_ON)


    if(QT_ON)
    #---------------------------ADD UI FILES---------------------------------------#
        file(GLOB ${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_UI src/*.ui)

        if(BUILD_${TARGET_NAME})
        #this macro doesn't get defined unless QtWidgets is found
            qt5_wrap_ui(${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_UI_HEADERS ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_UI})
        endif()
    #---------------------------ADD RESOUCE FILES----------------------------------#
        file(GLOB ${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_RESOURCE_FILES *.qrc)

        if(BUILD_${TARGET_NAME})
            #this macro doesn't get defined unless QtWidgets is found
            qt5_add_resources(${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_GENERATED_RESOURCES ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_RESOURCE_FILES})
        endif()
    endif(QT_ON)

    #..........................organize source/header files........................#
    source_group("Source Files" FILES ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_SOURCES})
    source_group("Header Files" FILES ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_HEADERS})

    if(QT_ON)
        source_group("Resource Files" FILES ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_RESOURCE_FILES})
        source_group("UI Files" FILES ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_UI})
        source_group("Generated Files" FILES ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_GENERATED_RESOURCES} ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_UI_HEADERS})
    endif()

    #---------------------------ADD TARGET-----------------------------------------#
    set(ALL_${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_FILES
        ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_CMAKELISTS}
        ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_SOURCES}
        ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_HEADERS}
        ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_RESOURCE_FILES}
        ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_UI}
        ${${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_GENERATED_RESOURCES}
    )

    if(${proj_type} STREQUAL "executable")
        add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${ALL_${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_FILES})
    elseif(${proj_type} STREQUAL "library")
        add_library(${TARGET_NAME} STATIC ${ALL_${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_FILES})
    else()
        add_custom_target(${TARGET_NAME} ${ALL_${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_FILES})
    endif()

endmacro()
```

If that's still not enough, here's how the subprojects are included in the module-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
foreach (MODULE_NAME ${MODULES})
    add_subdirectory (${MODULE_NAME})
endforeach()
```

CMake version used: 3.1.3

Answer (score -1):

How do you manage dependencies between libs with CMake? This should be done using TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myexe mylib1 mylib2)

Comment: Consider commenting if you want to clarify the question. Yes, I'm using target_link_libraries, what else?

Comment: Not enough informations to help here. Maybe describe your project architecture, folders, how you use CMakeLists.txt for principal project and subprojects.

Comment: See the edit I've added. From my experience, questions that are too long scare away people, so I doubt this will help me.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems quite correct, without details and running it, not easy to say. If link command line is exactly the same, it means the libs  are not the same. Unless libs are not found because of library path that would be different, but you would have an error about library not found.  Maybe compare the libs with the 2 architectures to be sure they have all symbols inside.

Comment: Looking at symbols is an idea, thanks. I'll be sure to try that.